# Android Studio says (in gradle file) that there is newer version of library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, picasso

Android studio says that:

"A newer version of com.squareup.picasso:picasso than 2.8 is available: 2.71828"

[Screenshot from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btFE9.png)

but I see that 2.8 is the newest version on https://github.com/square/picasso/releases.

My Gradle build script for Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I guess that Gradle looks not on GitHub, but on some other repository? If yes, should I change

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
```

to something like

```
implementation 'com.github.square:picasso:2.8'
```

or should I change to:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: Does it fix it if you do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` ?

Comment: @MSpeed - no, tested before I wrote here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue on their [GitHub](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/2179)

As stated:

> Updated Picasso version 2.71828 to 2.8. Now Android Lint complains
> that there is a newer version 2.71828 available. Which is true in
> semantic versioning sense since 71828 > 8.
>
> One can suppress the GradleDependency lint check for the library to
> get rid of the warning. However, I would find it better if version
> number components were monotonically increasing instead.

So leave it as is.

If it really bothers you, you can do this to suppress the warning:

```
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to understand if I am doing something wrong, or knew the explanation - which you provided.

Comment: No problem mate glad to be of help!